# What's the best way to edit a text file record using shell?

Tags: shell, unix

I have data file that stores records like this:

```
make=honda|model=civic|color=red
make=toyota|model=corolla|color=blue
```

What would be the best way to detect (based on the make field) whether a given make exists in the file and then replace it with a new record? (Using shell script)

Comment: you have shown your data file, now show your actual file that you want to make amendment and describe your final output by examples

Answer (score 2):

For your purposes, the best solution is probably either [the stream editor](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) or [awk](http://www.vectorsite.net/tsawk.html).

Comment: I know already how to detect the record (awk). But is there a good way of replacing it? Can I use SED somehow to do that?

Comment: If only there were some way to turn the words "the stream editor" into some sort of magical portal to the documentation for itself...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script that uses a `sed` command that will do it:

```
filename='cars'
make='toyota'
replacement='make=nissan|model=sentra|color=green'
sed "s/^make=$make.*/$replacement/" $filename
```

There are a couple of problems with **icarus127**'s answer which I have fixed and addressed here:

```
filename='cars'
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
# no need to call external cat, make the array at the same time the file is read
lines=($(<$filename))
# IMO, it's better and makes a difference to save and restore IFS instead of unsetting it
IFS="$saveIFS"

make='toyota'
replacement='make=nissan|model=sentra|color=green'

# the array variable MUST be quoted here or it won't work correctly
for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
    # you can use Bash's regex matching to avoid repeatedly calling
    # multiple external programs in a loop
    if [[ $line =~ ^make=$make ]]
    then
        echo "$replacement"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi    
done
```

**However**, that (and the `cat` version) reads the whole file into an array, which could be a problem if it's large. It's better to use `read` in a `while` loop with a redirect:

```
filename='cars'

make='toyota'
replacement='make=nissan|model=sentra|color=green'

while read -r line
do
    # you can use Bash's regex matching to avoid repeatedly calling
    # multiple external programs in a loop
    if [[ $line =~ ^make=$make ]]
    then
        echo "$replacement"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi    
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: +1 For improving my script.  I'm at best a novice and it's great to see better ways of doing things.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it in bash.

```
#get the file and create an array separated by new lines
lines=$(cat $filename)
IFS=$'\n'
lines=( $lines )
unset IFS


for line in ${lines[@]}
do
    #Get the value of make from the current line
    make=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "|" -f1 | cut -d "=" -f2)

    if [[ "$make" == "$makeImLookingFor" ]]
    then
        echo "modified line"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

by sed this is is a way

contents of temp.txt
make=honda|model=civic|color=red
make=toyota|model=corolla|color=blue

new_rec="make=honda|model=civic|color=blue"

$ sed -e "s/^make=honda.*/$new_rec/g" temp.txt
make=honda|model=civic|color=blue
make=toyota|model=corolla|color=blue

hope this helps